# Cas 5.3.1 st.timeToKillInSeconds is not work

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

```
##
# Ticket expired
#
cas.ticket.st.numberOfUses=1
#cas.ticket.st.timeToKillInSeconds=60
cas.ticket.st.timeToKillInSeconds=30


cas.ticket.tgt.timeToKillInSeconds=180
cas.ticket.tgt.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds=28800
```

I have set the expire policy of TGT and ST. But it didn't work where the time is up. Debug the code, process didn't go into the MultiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy and change a new ST to update lastTimeUsed of TGT. On the otherwise, I share the ticket with redis; As I understand it, every request for a ST (or PT) will extend the life of the TGT by timeToKillInSeconds up to maxTimeToLiveInSeconds.